# change url with history.pushState

Tags: jquery, url

I have a page with products and 1 filter bar.

filter bar has 2 options:

1. category
2. subcategory.

I want every time I select category display all items and when i select subcategory display only items of this subcategory, something like :

```
category -> tv and subcategory -> samsung ,lg, sony.
```

Every time i select category i load items with ajax and when i select subcategory i hide everything is not in the selected subcategory with jquery.

So i need every time i am pressing selectors to change the url like : `localhost/tv` or `localhost/tv/sony`.

I found **historyPushstate** but the problem is that when i press the back button the page doesn't display the previous content.

I found **history.js** on github and similar questions but they are old.I want to ask :

1. Can i use jquery  when i click the back button on browser
2. Is history.js still good or i have to find something newer for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you can use jQuery
2) [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) is not deprecated, so you can use it. You always can use [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) as alternative.

Comment: which way is the best?

Comment: @andrian I have used vanilla JS version and it fits my needs fine. There is no *best* way.